# C++ redraw with DrawText

Tags: c++, winforms, drawtext

Currently i'm drawing the text from a textbox in my window. I successfully get the text i need to draw and it draws the text. It's ok.

Here's the problem: when i write something else in my input box and draw the text again (via button push), the new text is drawn right on top of the previous text as to be expected.

I'm new to all of this and i can't find a way to clear the previous text before drawing the new text.

Here's my code:

```
void DrawMyText(HWND hwnd) {

    int iTextLength = GetWindowTextLength(hDrawInput) + 1;
    char cDrawText[1000] = "";
    HDC wdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);    
    RECT canvas;
    canvas.left   = 168;
    canvas.top    = 108;
    canvas.right  = 500;
    canvas.bottom = 500;

    GetWindowText(hDrawInput, cDrawText, iTextLength);

    SetTextColor(wdc, 0x00FF0066);
    SetBkMode(wdc,TRANSPARENT);
    DrawText(wdc, cDrawText, -1, &canvas, DT_LEFT);

    DeleteDC(wdc);
}
```

Any tips on how to do this? I will gladly provide any additional information if needed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DrawText is more like a spray can - it paints over top whatever is already there. I'd recommend switching to SetWindowText. The difference is DrawText is more like a canvas rendering call, and doesn't consider much about the type of control it's drawing to. SetWindowText is an explicit "set the text of this window to this specific value", and is specific to text-based controls. More to the point, it will replace the current text with the new text value.

If you absolutely must do it with DrawText (i.e. you prefer a canvas approach as above), then you'll have to manually clear the text area yourself with something like  InvalidateRect() (using the RECT of the text area). Or, by drawing a rectangle equal in size to the text area and with the same color as the background. Let me know if that's not enough detail.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would absolutely like to use anything other but I absolutely must use DrawText, it's a university assignment. I thougt about drawing over with the background color but i'd like to leave it as the last possible option. I tried `InvalidateRect(hwnd, &canvas, TRUE);` right before I draw again but it seems to do nothing. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Hmm. Instead of InvalidateRect(), try FillRect(wdc, &canvas, brush), where brush is a simple brush you've created to be the cleared background (probably just white?). InvalidateRect() should force a repaint, but depending on whatever else you have going on it's tricky. FillRect may give you better results. Obviously, be sure to do FillRect before the call DrawText.

Comment: I like the spray can analogy.  `InvalidateRect` is generally the right thing to do, but it requires you to handle the resulting paint message and draw your text after the background has been redrawn.

Comment: @MikeD Well, it works, thanks to everyone who helped with tips and solutions!

Answer (score 1):

If some other window covers and then uncovers the place where you drew the text it will be gone! The illusion that windows can sit on top of each other is destroyed! Windows provides a scheme to overcome this problem but you are not cooperating with the scheme.

Paint your text only in response to the WM_PAINT message, using the BeginPaint and EndPaint API calls. On the button click just call InvalidateRect, which asks Windows to send you a WM_PAINT. BeginPaint erases your window just before you paint. So by putting your painting code in the right place - the WM_PAINT handler - you solve two problems: It erases any old text, and it repaints whenever your window is uncovered.